# ColdFusion 2018 u15 Administrator missing links to log files

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I recently upgraded ColdFusion 2018 from u13 to u15.  I updated the JVM to be 11.0.17.

[image]

[image]

After a reboot & Ctrl+F5, the CF Admin > Debugging & Logging > Log Files does not have links for viewing the log files within the CF Admin page.  All of the log files seem to have the "Archive log file" and "Disable logging" buttons, but are missing the "Search/View log file", "Download log file" and "Delete log file" buttons.

[image]

No errors are appearing in the F12/Dev tools for the console or networking tab (all 200's) for this page.

Any ideas on how to get the admin links to log files working again?  I don't want to downgrade the CF update, but could this be a JVM issue?  Does anyone know if a previous JVM version has this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removal of the log browser was intentional. It apparently closed a security issue. It is noted in the release announcement: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-2018-update-15.html.